# How to vary the range used in NPV formula?

Tags: excel

=NPV(D2,B3:B & C2)

I have a NPV formula in cell B2. The interest rate is in D2. I want the range that the formula works with to vary by whatever value is in C2. ie if the value in C2 = 362 the formula should be =NPV(D2,B3:B362) I have tried to concatenate as above but this is wrong. How do I vary the range in the NPV formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best done probably with offset, which allows you define a range of cells:

```
offset(base_cell, row_offset, col_offset, height, width)
```

in your case you should use:

```
npv(d2, offset(b3, 0, 0, C2 - 3, 1))
```

note you should enter this using ctrl-shift-enter so that excel knows it is an array function.

A second method which is possible but not advisable in your case is to use indirect. This changes strings into cell references..

```
npv(d2, indirect("b3:b"&c2))
```

again you need to enter it as an array formula. This method might look better but it is much more difficult to maintain and is probably less efficient so you should get used to offset.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the INDIRECT function to select a cell based on a string.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

```
=NPV(D2, B3:INDIRECT("B"&C2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` are `volatile functions`, and thus should be avoided wherever possible. Hence I would prefer:

`=NPV(D2,B3:INDEX(B:B,C2))`

Regards